# Firewall blocks FTP PASV response

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, ftp, firewall

I have an FTP server that supports passive server mode (using PASV command). This works fine with Windows XP. When I want to access this server from Windows Vista or Windows 7 with firewall enabled I experience an immediate connection shutdown. A reset packet is sent to the server, and the socket is signaled that the server has reset the connection (what is not true).

The problem disappears when the firewall is disabled.

Connections to other FTP servers work correctly. The difference is that the server's response to PASV does not enclose the address field with parentheses. This is legal as documented in RFC-959 and RFC-1132.

How can I configure the firewall to stop this bad behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure the firewall because it's just buggy.

As long as you can't change the FTP server to send the port information in parentheses because it's built in in old devices in the field, you need a special client with the following behavior.

This client must send a `TYPE I` command immediately before each `PASV` command to keep the firewall in a sane state. If you need a non-binary transfer you might change the parameter of the TYPE command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the parenthesis are to blame.
I would rather think that the dynamic port-range allocated by that server disagrees with Vista/7.

For a discussion of the subject, see this article :
[The default dynamic port range for TCP/IP has changed in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851)

To view the dynamic port range on your computer for ipv4, use the following command :

```
netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp
```

To set the dynamic port range for TCP, use for example :

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=1024 num=30000
```

More commands are described in the above article.

EDIT : Please note that the Windows firewall may be intelligent enough to open a dynamic port specified in the PASV response, even if this port doesn't fall within its default range for dynamic ports. But it may be that it is still not intelligent enough to understand the response without the parentheses. It may pay to have a look at the possibility of extending the default range for dynamic ports.

Comment: @harrymc: I have verified that the parenthesis are in question. The problem vanishes, when I change the FTP server to added parenthesis.

Comment: Is this your own ftp server and you control its source?

Comment: Yes, I can control the source for new devices. But changing existing devices in the field is very expensive.

Comment: Which ftp clients have you tried?

Comment: I have tried: Windows Explorer, FTP command line tool, TeraTerm. TeraTerm is no FTP client, but you can establish a TCP connection (FTP command connection) to the server. *This* connection is terminated by the firewall *immediately* before any data connection could be established. That's why the port range you mentioned can be ignored. The problem occurs *before* trying to establish any data connection.

Comment: I have added an edit. in addition: Is it a problem only of the Windows firewall? Do other firewalls on same OS behave differently?

Comment: I don't know how other firewalls behave. But I have to care for customers with the standard tools.

Comment: The behavior of other firewalls can only confirm the hypothesis that Windows firewall does not fully implement (as always) the standards for PASV answer as regarding parenthesis. The definitive answer requires using netsh as described above to verify whether your dynamic port is in the range acceptable to Windows firewall, so whether the firewall cuts the connection the moment the ftp client "suspiciously" tries to use a port that it considers as "dangerous".

Comment: Well, as my first comment shows: When the server sends the parenthesis the **active** firewall does not drop the connection.

Comment: Harper, the behavior of active and passive ftp is totally different as regarding ports. The firewall will have no problems with active ftp which uses only well-known ports (20,21). If you won't check the dynamic port range used with your server against the default allowed by Windows Vista/7, then we won't know whether my answer is right or wrong.

Comment: I have checked that the reset of the control connection occurs independent of the dynamic port range. I've done both: a) changing the port range b) sending the same port from the FTP server with and without parenthesis. Only the missing parenthesis cause a connection reset. So, unfortunately your answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It seems that you have found an idiosyncrasy in some FTP server and/or clients whose developers have not read the specs as well as you did ....

Comment: "The specs" for FTP is RFC959 (http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc959/?include_text=1). You can read a sample at page 39 with () and at page 45 without. So any implementation should accept both variants (with and without parentheseses). It wasn't bad if some clients would fail. It's also not a idiosyncrasy of the server, since it fulfills the spec. But the Windows 7 firewall breaks connection to servers for all clients, if the server omits the parentheses.

Comment: All you can do is file a bug report with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of an issue I had with Java and FTP running under Windows 7.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990663/java-7-prevents-ftp-transfers-on-windows-vista-and-7-if-firewall-is-on-any-idea

It ended up being a bug with Microsoft's firewall with FTP, passive mode, and IPv6 connections (the address did not need to be an IPv6 one, just the software that made the connection does so using the IPv6 stack).

The symptom described in your question sounds very similar to this issue, so I'll link and summarize here (even though this question has nothing to do with Java the fix may be the same)

A summary of a few solutions mentioned there:

- Microsoft hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2754804
- Attempt to make your FTP client running under Vista/7 run with an IPv4 stack (may be possible, may not be)
- Disable Windows firewall's stateful FTP using `netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable` (this however will disable non-passive mode FTP connections punching through your firewall)

Comment: This KB article describes the cause as a problem with the IPv4/IPv6 synchronization of dual mode sockets. It might be that the hotfix would also silently fix the parenthesis bug. But the hotfix should "only be applied to systems that experience the described proble". Since the problem isn't IPv6 related I am a bit reluctant to install it.